# Show that $((0,1)\times(0,1))\cup(\{1\}\times[0,1])$ is not a smooth manifold with boundary$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, manifolds-with-boundary

I have to show that $\left((0,1)\times(0,1)\right) \cup(\{1\}\times[0,1])$ is not a smooth manifold with boundary. I think that the problem points are (1,0) and (1,1) because their neighborhoods are not diffeomorphic to any open subset of $\mathbb{H}^2$, but I don't know how to show it.

Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In fact, their neighborhoods are not homeomorphic

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: This is not even a topological manifold with boundary. One clue is the fact that the boundary of a manifold with boundary is always a manifold without boundary. Once you know that, you can show that $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ cannot be either interior points or boundary points.